# Angular - Ensure that app.run() has executed

Tags: angularjs, routes, program-entry-point

I am using `app.run()` to fire a method that initializes a user session.

Now I was just adding another method to `app.run()` and discovered that some method in the routeProviders `resolve` fired asynchronously, overlapping with the session initialisation and therefore crashing the application.

How can I ensure that `app.run()` has executed before firing anything route related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do somthin async in your app.run() ??
this may help

```
angular.element(document).ready(
    function() {
        var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
        var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
        $http.get('/test.json').then(
            function (response) {
               var x = response.data;

               angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: well i was trying to do the same ...didnt work for me .so i made the async call and only after its resolved then manually bootsraped the app.

Comment: Updated the answ tell me if it helps